# Unable to see OPCUA protocol in wireshark

Tags: python, excel, pycharm, wireshark, opc-ua

created a simple client and server and tried to capture the action in wireshark but not able to see OPC UA protocol in the same.
I have done this code in pycharm on windows 10 can you please point out where the problem is to see the OPCUA protocol in wireshark
i have added server code that i have used and also added client code and attached wireshark image as a png file 
Server code:

```
from opcua import Server
from random import randint
from xlwt import Workbook
import datetime
import time

server = Server()
workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('sheet 1')
#sheet.write(j, 0, time.time())
#workbook.save("sub_ohio_latency_ACK.xls")
url = "opc.tcp://LAPTOP-9UCODEJ5:48020"

server.set_endpoint(url)
name = "OPCUA_Server"
addspace = server.register_namespace(name)

node = server.get_objects_node()

Param = node.add_object(addspace, "Parameters")

Temp = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Temperature",0)
Time = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Time",0)
i = Param.add_variable(addspace, "TagID", 0)

Temp.set_writable()
Time.set_writable()


l = server.get_objects_node()
p = server.get_node(Temp)
k = server.get_node(Time)
j = server.get_node(i)

print(k)
print(p)
print(l)
print(j)

server.start()
print("server started at ()".format(url))
c = 0
while True:

    Temperature = randint(0,20)
    TIME = datetime.datetime.now()
    TagID = c
    print(Temperature, TIME, c)

    Temp.set_value(Temperature)
    Time.set_value(TIME)
    i.set_value(c)
    c += 1
    #time.sleep(2)
```

Client Code

```
from opcua import Client
import time
from xlwt import Workbook

workbook =Workbook()
#workbook2=Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('sheet 1')

url = "opc.tcp://192.168.0.108:48020"

client = Client(url)
client.connect()
print("client connected")

for i in range(2000):
    objects = client.get_objects_node()
    l = client.get_node("ns=2;i=2")
    Temperature = l.get_value()
    #print(Temperature)
    k = client.get_node("ns=2;i=3")
    Time = k.get_value()
    j = client.get_node("ns=2;i=4")
    msg_tag = j.get_value()
    sheet.write(i, 0, msg_tag)
    sheet.write(i, 1, Temperature)
    sheet.write(i, 2, Time)
    sheet.write(i,3,time.time())
    workbook.save("test_client.xls")
    #print(Time)
    #print(msg_tag)
    #print(objects)
    #time.sleep(5)
client.disconnect()
print("client disconnected")
```

[WIreshark Ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN8XB.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the Wireshark OPC UA display filter only works with the default OPC UA TCP port (4840)

Since you use another port (48020) you need to update the list of TCP ports that will be associated with the OPC UA Binary protocol in order to let Wireshark know that it need to decode the packet on those ports as OPC UA packets.

You can update the list here: 
Wireshark - Edit - Preferences - Protocols- OpcUa - TCP Port(s)

[image: Wireshark OPC UA Binary Protocol TCP Ports]